# What does "populate" actually do in CMake documents?

Tags: cmake

I always confused when CMake documents say "populate the property". For example in

> target_include_directories( [SYSTEM] [BEFORE]
> <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]   [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>
> [items2...] ...])
>
> ...
>
> PRIVATE and PUBLIC items will **populate** the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
> property of <target>.

I'm not sure to populate the 'INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES' property with what?
For example `target_include_directories(A PUBLIC B)`, does 'populate `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`' here means to copy B's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` propery into A's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PRIVATE and PUBLIC items will populate the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of <target>.

It roughly does:

```
set(mode "PRIVATE") # or PUBLIC, from target_include_directories arguments

# Get interface include directories
target_get_proprety(incdirs B INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

if(mode STREQUAL "PUBLIC" OR mode STREQUAL "PRIVATE")
    set_properties(TARGET A APPEND PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${incdirs})
endif()

# when mode is PUBLIC or INTERFACE, they get also added to A's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
```

I think the word "*populate*" there could be replaced with "*append*" without losing meaning.

> I'm not sure to populate the 'INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES' property with what?

With the content of [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html?highlight=interface_include_directories) from the other target.

> For example target_include_directories(A PUBLIC B), does 'populate INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES' here means to copy B's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES propery into A's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property?

Means to append B's `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` into A's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and into A's `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

Comment: Hi KamilCuk, in the case `target_include_directories(A PUBLIC B)`, why B's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` not copys to A's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`?

Comment: Och, well, because they don't? `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` are meant to be private for `B` use.  ( But what is really happening behind the scenes, is that the string "B" is only added to A's `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` and then when `A` is compiled cmake searches via those properties, and if it's a target, it adds `INTERFACE_*` things to compile line. (or something like that) )

Comment: Oh, So not matter what cases(PUBLIC, PRIVATE, INTERFACE), B's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will not 'populate' to any properties of A, right? In other words, A only cares about B's  `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, not care B's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`?

Comment: As far as I know cmake: Right. Yes.

Comment: Gives me a feeling that the rule is similar to C++'s `public/private` field and `public/private` inheritance.